# How to resolve class conflict in import statements

Tags: java

Im trying to write a program that will read an xml file and print to itext.

However, I getting a class conflict in import statements. I dont know how to resolve this issue.

```
import org.dom4j.Document;
import org.dom4j.DocumentException;
import org.dom4j.Element;
import org.dom4j.Node;
import org.dom4j.io.SAXReader;

import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.w3c.dom.*;

import com.itextpdf.text.Annotation;
import com.itextpdf.text.BaseColor;
import com.itextpdf.text.Chunk;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Element;
import com.itextpdf.text.Font;
import com.itextpdf.text.FontFactory;
import com.itextpdf.text.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.Phrase;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfAction;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPCell;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
```

The "Document" and "Element" classes between dom4j and itext are conflicting.

Does anyone know a workaround? Is there any eclipse magic I can do?

Comment: "is there any eclipse magic I can do" <- You can try selecting "Source"->"Organize imports" and see if eclipse can automatically determine and add all the imports your class needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround here is to only import one of the two (or many) conflicting classes.  Then use the fully qualified class name for the class not imported.  For example:

```
import org.dom4j.Document;
// import com.itextpdf.text.Document;     <-- don't import this
```

Then when using the `itext` class, refer to it as:

```
com.itextpdf.text.Document doc;
```

I would recommed importing the class/package of classes which you use the most in your Java file.  This would let you avoid having to type a fully qualified class name as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

In such cases , you should use fully qualified class name for one of the conflicting classes while using it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the package when using them in your code.
Otherwise there is an ambiguity as `Document` could refer to either `org.dom4j.Document` or `com.itextpdf.text.Document` and `Element` could refer to `org.dom4j.Element` or `com.itextpdf.text.Element`.

Comment: Is there any way to add a namespace to the two dom4j and itext?

Answer (score 0):

Import statements in *Java* act like aliases for fully qualified type names. Trying to use the same alias for two or more types won't work because of ambiguity.

Therefore do either not use import statements for any of those conflicting types and use their fully qualified names (package plus type name) or import at most one of those types only.

Comment: Ive tried the fully qualified name. But, Im still getting the error on the import statements.

Comment: You have to remove all conflicting import statements. Try and remove `import org.w3c.dom.*` which does import a lot of types. Config eclipse to never use `*` imports. One ovious conflict is `import org.dom4j.Document;` and `import com.itextpdf.text.Document;`. You have to remove at least one of them. The same is true for other imports ending into the same type name.