# Reduce JAVA FQDN class name

Tags: java

JAVA noob question.

I have two conflicting class coming from two different packages `a.b.c.d.A` and `x.y.z.A`.
These FQDNs are almost same size making argument names cross 100 column boundary nad making code look really ugly.

Is there java equivalent of c++ `using`?

Any way I can use both classes without FQDN?

Sorry if this is asked already, not aware of correct terminology.

Comment: There's no way to use both of them using just the short name *in the same source file*.

Answer (score 0):

You could import one of the conflicting classes and use the fully qualified name for the other, as recommended here.

[How to resolve class conflict in import statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44415525/how-to-resolve-class-conflict-in-import-statements)

Somebody sent a bug report asking for aliases to prevent using full names, but it was dismissed.

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4478140

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).